# Find eigenvalues of $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following matrix:
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&1&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I tried finding the characteristic polynomial, so I calculated the determinant of:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda&-1&1&0\\
0&-\lambda&0&0\\
1&0&-\lambda&-1\\
0&1&-1&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So we get:
$
-\lambda
\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda&1&0\\
1&-\lambda&-1\\
0&-1&-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=
-\lambda\cdot(-\lambda(\lambda^2-1)-(-\lambda))=\lambda^2((\lambda^2-1)-1)=\lambda^2(\lambda^2-2).
$

However, Mathematica tells me the eigenvalues are $0,-2,2$ instead of $0,\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2$. I don't see what I'm doing wrong - could someone help me?

*EDIT*

OK, it's solved! I realised what I did wrong: I did the following row operation on the original matrix: $R_2\to R_2+R_3$, thinking the determinant would stay the same - however, I should have considered row operations on the matrix $A-\lambda I$, instead of on $A$.

Comment: In the second matrix you wrote the elements in position $21$ and $31$ should be $-1$ and $1$, not $0$.

Comment: @Crostul Oh wait, I know what I did wrong. I did an elementary row operation on the original matrix (let's call it $A$) where the determinant would stay the same, instead of on the matrix $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: @Crostul ... there are two components that are wrong ... the OP needs to do a little edit ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit No edit is needed. The OP is asking where is the mistake. The mistake is in copying the wrong matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do row operation before computing the characteristic polynomial!

The characteristic polynomial is
$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda&-1&1&0\\
-1&-\lambda&0&1\\
1&0&-\lambda&-1\\
0&1&-1&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}=
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&1-\lambda^2&-\lambda\\
-1&-\lambda&0&1\\
1&0&-\lambda&-1\\
0&1&-1&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}=
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&1-\lambda^2&-\lambda\\
0&-\lambda&-\lambda&0\\
1&0&-\lambda&-1\\
0&1&-1&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(I did $R_1+\lambda R_3$ and then $R_2+R_3$). Expanding with respect to the first column gives
$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1-\lambda^2&-\lambda\\
-\lambda&-\lambda&0\\
1&-1&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}=
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-\lambda^2&-2\lambda\\
0&-2\lambda&-\lambda^2\\
1&-1&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}=
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda^2&-2\lambda\\
-2\lambda&-\lambda^2
\end{bmatrix}=\lambda^4-4\lambda^2
$$
so the eigenvalues are $0$ (double), $2$ and $-2$.

### Alternative method

Gaussian elimination on the matrix $A$ gives
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&1&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1\\
-1&0&0&1\\
0&-1&1&0\\
0&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix} &&R_1\leftrightarrow R_3
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&1&0\\
0&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix} &&R_2\gets R_2+R_1
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&-1&0\\
0&-1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix} &&R_2\leftrightarrow R_4
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix} &&R_3\gets R_3+R_2
\end{align}
which shows $0$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $2$.

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&1&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $2$ is an eigenvalue. Similarly
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&1&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $-2$ is an eigenvalue.

Hence the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $2$, and the characteristic polynomial is $(0-\lambda)^2(2-\lambda)(-2-\lambda)$

Comment: Ah, in hindsight, you can actually "see" the eigenvectors quite easily, indeed. I guess when a matrix has some pattern in it, it might be a good idea to see what you can calculate in your head.